How to import Sentinel 2 data using the command line
I am encountering the following reported error while importing the Sentinel 2 data given by the official website using the command line:

I doubt if it has anything to do with projection? Can anyone give me some advice on this? I'm not too familiar with GRASS GIS as I'm a new user to it.

Please edit your question to use text for code/command line and errors not screenshots.  You can use the {} button in the toolbar to apply code formatting to the text.

Please add the output of g.proj -w to understand which projection you are using.
